# how do I insert data into a datagridview via combobox when you have an integer column (CategoryID) and text in the combobox?

Tags: c#, database, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwEbs.jpg)
this is where I want to insert the data into the database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbojA.jpg)
In this code, I have absolutely no idea how to do it. I searched the whole Internet, but I found a video of some Spaniard, but he uses procedures there, and I don't know how to use them. Can you recommend an easier way?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMgfmNdxNsw&list=WL&index=15&t=568s

**C#**

```
private void add_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string insert_query = "insert into toy (name, price, amount, categoryid) values (@e1, @e2, @e3, )";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_query, menu.connection);
            try
            {
                menu.connection.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e1", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e2", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e3", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", comboBox1.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            finally
            { menu.connection.Close(); }
            get_data(); // update table
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please format your code. If you don't format your code, it is uncomfortable to read it.
(https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help -> syntax highlighting)

If you want to mix an integer value with a string, maybe it would be helpful for you to try to build a string and then you can insert it into a datagrid cell.

```cs
textBox1.Text = 0;
textBox2.Text = "text";
string z = textBox1.Text + textBox2Text; // = "0text"

cmd.Parameters.AddWithVale("@e1", z)
```